# How to format complete Jalaali date with moment js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

My value is like this:

```
13990125122957
```

and I want to format it to 1399/01/25.

Comment: A simple [*search*](https://www.google.com/search?q=moment.js+Jalaali+calendar&oq=moment.js+Jalaali+calendar) will lead to plugins for moment.js to handle Jalaali dates. `13990125122957` is sometime in 2413 Gregorian.

Comment: This type of question is really off topic here as it's essentially asking for an off site resource and shows no attempt at finding an answer yourself. It would be better asked on a moment.js support forum. If your value is just YYYYMMDDHHmmss then you don't need a date library at all.

Comment: E.g. `let [y, yy, m, d, rest] = '13990125122957'.match(/\d\d/g); console.log(y+yy+'/'+m+'/'+d);`

Comment: you are completely right, thanks for your comments

Comment: BTW, if you just want today's date in that format, you can use [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat): `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-CA-u-ca-islamic',{day: '2-digit',month: '2-digit',year: 'numeric'}).format(new Date()).replace(/-/g,'/')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use moment plugin [Jalaali Calendar](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/)

> If you want to work with Jalaali calendar system (Jalali, Persian, Khorshidi or Shamsi), you can use Behrang Noruzi Niya's plugin moment-jalaali.
>
> When installed, it will wrap moment and moment will be able to format and parse Jalaali years and months. Here is a short example:
>
> ```
> var m = moment('1360/5/26', 'jYYYY/jM/jD'); // Parse a Jalaali date.
> m.format('jYYYY/jM/jD [is] YYYY/M/D'); // 1360/5/26 is 1981/8/17
> ```
>
> The repository is located at [github.com/behrang/moment-jalaali](https://github.com/behrang/moment-jalaali).

Working example for your input:

```js
console.log(moment("13990125122957", "jYYYYjMMjDDHH:mm:ss").format("jYYYY/jMM/jDD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-jalaali@0.9.2/build/moment-jalaali.js"></script>
```